# I want to unzip my animation.zip file in to the res/drawable-hdpi

Tags: android, zip4j

```
public void onClick(View v)

{

    try {

        // Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.

        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/sdcard/animation.zip");

        // Extracts all files to the path specified
        zipFile.extractAll("/sdcard/");

    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This is what i have done.

I am able to unzip my `animation.zip` file on sdcard but i want to unzip it in res/drawable-hdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can never unzip a zip file to res folder. In mobile, you can unzip it to an SD card or your data/data folder. I think you want to change app's skin this way, but it is impossible. If you want to change the skin follow this [Android add extra skin as separate APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644076/android-add-extra-skin-as-separate-apk)

Comment: no, i want to unzip that dir and wnt to use in frame animation. if you could help me with that plz help me