# How to access files under assets folder of other apk's?

Tags: android, android-assets

When we browse any apk we found there is one folder named assets. Now I want to access that folder programatically. so how should I proceed for that? (Input for the program will be apk file/just app name).

Answer (score 19):

This will list all the files in the assets folder:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

This to open a certian file:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open(assetName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it is returning me only the files of my own application and i want to access the assets folder of another application.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454477/access-assests-from-another-application

Comment: You are not authorized to access other apps assets. Why would you want to do this anyway ?

Comment: if i am having apk file of any application then i think it should be retrievable

Comment: this only display to me "drawable, images sounds, webkit" and not the files  I put into the assets directory?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access file from assets folder use the following code:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("contacts.csv");
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(is);
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Answer (score 2):

For example: If you  have the .ttf file in your assets folder: 
then you  used like this:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MARKER.TTF");
```

Here is link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode