# Whats the actual path to be followed to get a file placed in assets folder for webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have a "index.html" file which I have placed inside a folder named "webpages" and this page is under assets folder in an hierarchy as

**my_android_project --> assets --> webpages --> index.html**

now in my webview code -

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);           

            myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/webpages/index.html");
```

still my webview says webpage not found. Please guide. I am new to android. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387637/how-to-access-file-under-assets-folder-in-android should help, avoid hardcoding file paths.

Comment: tried without hardcoded file path..not working :(

Comment: remove the s from /android_assets/. This may not fix it however, an answer to another question suggests this does not work in honeycomb+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory

Comment: No problem, I'll add it as an answer, can you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the s from /android_assets/ as seen in the code here should fix your issue, but beware of the comment that says it does not work in honeycomb.

[Webview load html from assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
"/webpages/index.html".
```