# android access pdf files from assests folder

Tags: android, file, pdf, android-intent, android-assets

In my application i want to store a PDF file in assets and when the view button is pressed ,  the PDF should be viewed by 3rd party applications installed in the device.

By using the below code ,  i tried to access the PDF file inside assets folder but  app says '**File not available**' . I searched over stackoverflow for various code and none of them worked.But when i tried to extract the APK file i could be able to see the PDF file inside assets folder.

The following is the code i tried :

```
File file = new File("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/ccv.pdf");

            if (file.exists()) {

                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(home.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(home.this, 
                        "File not available", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

So please provide the code snippet to access PDF file inside assets folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

File file = new File("file:///android_asset" + "/ccv.pdf");

            if (file.exists()) {

                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(home.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(home.this, 
                        "File not available", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: what u do u put that pdf file in folder or direcly in assets or please try this using direct link in intent

Comment: i have put the file in assets folder . here is the screenshot : http://tinypic.com/r/2yvw7kk/8

Comment: let me check again because it is working fine in my case wait

Comment: can you please remove the if file exist check

Comment: because file is working for external storage not for raw and assets folder

Answer (score 0):

> *i tried to access the PDF file inside assets folder*

for that,

```
new File("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/ccv.pdf");
```

is not going to get you the assets path.

[`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())  just

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where
>   files created

To access Assets, use [`getAssets()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets())  or [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

You can refer [how-to-access-file-under-assets-folder-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387637/how-to-access-file-under-assets-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

At last i was able to find the answer , Assets cannot be accessed using File , only it can be accessed using Assetmanager

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream ims = assetManager.open("ccv.pdf");
```

Comment: Accept your own answer, so it will be useful for others.