# How to get path of any file from my my application data folder

Tags: android, android-assets

My application files are bellow, I want to get `sharethis.png` file in java code , What is syntax ?

[image]

I used this ...

`Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/www/sharethis.png");`

but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the assets **dir**, put the file into `/res/raw` , and you can then access it using the following **URI:** `android.resource://com.your.packagename/" + R.raw.sharethis`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Bitmap shareThis = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.shareThis);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference it from a JavaScript or html file in your `assets` folder, use `file:///android_asset/www/sharethis.jpg`.

Otherwise, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387637/how-to-access-file-under-assets-folder-in-android), this will list all the files in the assets folder:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

This to open a certain file:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open(assetName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 try {

    // get input stream

    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("sharethis.png");

    // load image as Drawable

    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);

}

catch(IOException ex) {

      Log.e("I/O ERROR","Failed")
}
```