# Android: loading files

Tags: android, file

I'm need to load a file(my model) on android device. I use

```
FileReader fr = null;
try {fr = new FileReader(new File(path));} catch (Exception e) {}
BufferedReader reader =...
```

what would be the correct path for the file(like what folder do you start from). Also where would the standard place for keeping models or other text files be.

Comment: sdcard/yourapp/files  , normally external storage your app name and place them how ever inside that folder

Answer (score 0):

External storage is a good place for it:

```
    public static File getMyFilePath(String filename){
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd_HH.mm.ss.S");
        return new File(getDirectory(context, VIDEO_DIR),fileName);
    }
    private static File getDirectory(Context ctx, String path){
        File f=new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()+path);
        f.mkdirs();
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: I'm coding in android studio, how can I save a file to external storage?

Comment: @Shadow check out this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: @Shadow maybe you search for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanks... So for game assets it's better to use internal storage; but how do you access  the assets folder?

Comment: @Shadow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387637/how-to-access-file-under-assets-folder