# java.io.FileNotFoundException: abaa.wav?

Tags: java, android

I have an audio file with the name `abaa.wav` in assets folder in android studio project. You can see the image:
[image: abaa.wav in assets folder]
then, I do not know why the error appears `java.io.FileNotFoundException:` you can see from the log:

```
05-22 13:34:56.067 12052-12052/com.ringdroid D/WAVE: EXCEPTION 
                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: abaa.wav
                                                     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
                                                     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:327)
                                                     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:301)
                                                     at com.ringdroid.spectrogram.WaveTools.wavread(WaveTools.java:41)
                                                     at com.ringdroid.spectrogram.SpectrogramActivity.onCreate(SpectrogramActivity.java:67)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code snippet From this log `com.ringdroid.spectrogram.WaveTools.wavread(WaveTools.java:41)` is => `is2 =mCtx.getAssets().open(path);`

and the code snippet from this log `at com.ringdroid.spectrogram.SpectrogramActivity.onCreate(SpectrogramActivity.java:67)` is => `audioBuf = WaveTools.wavread(inputPath, this);`

This is my class `WaveTools.java:`

```
public class WaveTools {

static byte[] myData = null;
public static byte[] myData2 = null;
static int mySampleRate;


public static float [] wavread(String path, Context mCtx) {

    String strThrow = "Error";
    InputStream inFile = null;
    byte[] tmpLong = new byte[4];
    byte[] tmpInt = new byte[2];

    long myChunkSize;
    long mySubChunk1Size;
    int myFormat;
    long myChannels;

    long myByteRate;
    int myBlockAlign;
    int myBitsPerSample;
    long myDataSize = 0;
    float [] buffer = null;

    myData = null;
    try{

        InputStream is2 = null;

        is2 =mCtx.getAssets().open(path);
        inFile = new DataInputStream(is2);




        String chunkID ="" + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read();

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the ChunkSize
        myChunkSize = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);


        String format = "" + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read();

        if (!format.equals("WAVE")){
            strThrow="File format is not .wav";
            throw new IllegalStateException(strThrow);
        }
        //Log.d("WAVE","format = "+format);
        String subChunk1ID = "" + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read();

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the SubChunk1Size
        mySubChunk1Size = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the audio format.  This should be 1 for PCM
        myFormat = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);
        //Log.d("WAVE","myFormat = "+myFormat);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the # of channels (1 or 2)
        myChannels = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        if (myChannels > 1){
            strThrow = "File format is not mono";
            throw new IllegalStateException(strThrow);
        }
        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the samplerate
        mySampleRate = (int)byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);
        //Log.d("WAVE","channels = "+myChannels);
        if (mySampleRate > mySampleRate){
            strThrow = "File format is not 8kHz";
            throw new IllegalStateException(strThrow);
        }
        Log.d("WAVE","Fs = "+mySampleRate);
        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the byterate
        myByteRate = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);


        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the blockalign
        myBlockAlign = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);


        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the bitspersample
        myBitsPerSample = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        String dataChunkID = "" + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read() + (char)inFile.read();

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the size of the data
        myDataSize = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);


        // read the data chunk
        myData = new byte[(int)myDataSize];
        myData2 = new byte[(int)myDataSize];

        Short [] shortVal = new Short[(int) myDataSize/2];

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2);
        int max = 0;
        buffer = new float[(int) myDataSize/2];
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<myDataSize;i+=2){
            inFile.read(tmpInt);
            myData[i]= tmpInt[0];
            myData[i+1]= tmpInt[1];
            bb.position(0);
            bb.put(tmpInt[0]);
            bb.put(tmpInt[1]);
            buffer[count] = (float)  bb.getShort(0);
            shortVal[count] = bb.getShort(0);
            //Log.d("Audio Read","myFormat = "+shortVal[count]);
            if (shortVal[count] > max){
                max = shortVal[count];
            }else if (-shortVal[count] > max){
                max =  -shortVal[count];
            }

            count++;

        }
        int inc = 0;
        ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2);
        bb2.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        for (int i=0; i<((int) myDataSize/2) ;i++){

            shortVal[i] = (short) (((int)shortVal[i]*32767)/max);
            bb2.putShort(0,shortVal[i]);
            myData2[inc] = bb2.get(0);
            myData2[inc+1] = bb2.get(1);
            inc = inc +2;

        }
        // close the input stream
        inFile.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.d("WAVE", "EXCEPTION ",e);

    }

    return buffer;

}

public static long byteArrayToLong(byte[] b)
{
    int start = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int len = 4;
    int cnt = 0;
    byte[] tmp = new byte[len];
    for (i = start; i < (start + len); i++)
    {
        tmp[cnt] = b[i];
        cnt++;
    }
    long accum = 0;
    i = 0;
    for ( int shiftBy = 0; shiftBy < 32; shiftBy += 8 )
    {
        accum |= ( (long)( tmp[i] & 0xff ) ) << shiftBy;
        i++;
    }
    return accum;
}

public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b)
{
    int start = 0;
    int low = b[start] & 0xff;
    int high = b[start+1] & 0xff;
    return (int)( high << 8 | low );
}

public static byte [] getByteArray(){

    return myData2;
}

public static int getFs() {

    return mySampleRate;
}
}
```

This is my class `SpectrogramActivity.java:`

```
public class SpectrogramActivity extends Activity {

float[] buff;
float[] buff_audio;
float[] new_sig;
TextView left;
TextView right;
TextView title;
int tshift = 4; //frame shift in ms
int tlen = 32; //frame length in ms
static float [] audioBuf;
static String inputPath;


// test


float[] array_hat,res=null;
float[] fmag = null;
float[] flogmag = null;
float[] fft_cpx,tmpr,tmpi;
float[] mod_spec =null;
float[] real_mod = null;
float[] imag_mod = null;
double[] real =null;
double[] imag= null;
double[] mag =null;
double[] phase = null;
double[] logmag = null;
static float [][] framed;
static int n, seg_len,n_shift;
static float n_segs;
float [] time_array;
float [] array;
float [] wn;
double[] nmag;
static float [][] spec;
float [] array2;
static float max;
static float min;
static float smax;
static float smin;
static float mux;
static float smux;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetupUI();
    // Acquire input audio file
    inputPath = "abaa.wav";
    try{

        audioBuf = WaveTools.wavread(inputPath, this);


    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("SpecGram2","Exception= "+e);
    }

    /*  Calculate Log Spectrogram data, ideally you
     *  would do this in a worker thread or an
     *  AsynTask so you don't consume UI resources
     */
    String dummy = "test";
    new calcSpec().execute(dummy);
}


/**
 * Draw layout
 */
private void SetupUI() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            (float) 1.0f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            (float) 1.0f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            (float) 0.1f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            (float) 1.0f);

    LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout secondary = new LinearLayout(this);
    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
    title = new TextView(this);
    left = new TextView(this);


    scroll.setLayoutParams(param4);
    main.setLayoutParams(param4);
    main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    secondary.setLayoutParams(param1);
    secondary.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    title.setLayoutParams(param3);
    left.setLayoutParams(param2);


    secondary.addView(left);
    scroll.addView(secondary);

    main.addView(title);
    main.addView(scroll);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spectrogram);
    title.setText("FFT Spectrogram of speech example by DigiPhD");
    title.setTextSize(12);
    title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    left.setText("Calculating.....\n");


}

/**
 * Calculates the spectrogram or log spectrum of the
 * audio signal
 * @param data
 * @param nsegs
 * @param nshift
 * @param seglen
 */
public void specGram(float [] data, float nsegs, int nshift, int seglen){

    spec = new float[seglen][(int)nsegs];
    array2 = new float[seglen];
    seg_len = seglen;
    n_segs = nsegs;
    n_shift = nshift;
    time_array = new float[data.length];
    time_array = data;

    framed = new float [seg_len][(int)n_segs];
    framed = FrameSig();
    minmax(framed,seg_len,(int)n_segs);
    meansig((int)n_segs);

    array = new float[seg_len*2];


    res=new float[seg_len];
    fmag = new float[seg_len];
    flogmag = new float[seg_len];

    mod_spec =new float[seg_len];
    real_mod = new float[seg_len];
    imag_mod = new float[seg_len];
    real = new double[seg_len];
    imag= new double[seg_len];
    mag = new double[seg_len];
    phase = new double[seg_len];
    logmag = new double[seg_len];
    nmag = new double[seg_len];
    for (int i = 0;i<seg_len*2;i++){
        array[i] = 0;
    }


    for (int j=0;j<nsegs; j++){
        FFT fft = new FFT(seg_len*2, 8000);
        for (int i = 0;i<seg_len;i++){
            array[i] = framed [i][j];
        }
        fft.forward(array);
        fft_cpx=fft.getSpectrum();
        tmpi = fft.getImaginaryPart();
        tmpr = fft.getRealPart();


        for(int i=0;i<seg_len;i++)
        {

            real[i] = (double) tmpr[i];
            imag[i] = (double) tmpi[i];

            mag[i] = Math.sqrt((real[i]*real[i]) + (imag[i]*imag[i]));
            mag[i] = Math.abs(mag[i]/seg_len);


            logmag[i] = 20*Math.log10(mag[i]);
            phase[i]=Math.atan2(imag[i],real[i]);

            /****Reconstruction****/
            //real_mod[i] = (float) (mag[i] * Math.cos(phase[i]));
            //imag_mod[i] = (float) (mag[i] * Math.sin(phase[i]));
            spec[(seg_len-1)-i][j] = (float) logmag[i];

            //Log.d("SpecGram","log= "+logmag[i]);
        }
    }
    minmaxspec(spec,seg_len,(int)nsegs);
    meanspec((int)nsegs);
    //fft.inverse(real_mod,imag_mod,res);

}
/**
 * Calculates the mean of the fft magnitude spectrum
 * @param nsegs
 */
private void meanspec(int nsegs) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int j=1; j<(int)nsegs; j++) {
        for (int i = 0;i<seg_len;i++){

            sum += spec[i][j];
        }
    }


    sum = sum/(nsegs*seg_len);
    mux = sum;

}
/**
 * Calculates the min and max of the fft magnitude
 * spectrum
 * @param spec
 * @param seglen
 * @param nsegs
 * @return
 */
public static float minmaxspec(float[][] spec, int seglen, int nsegs) {

    smin = (float) 1e35;
    smax = (float) -1e35;
    for (int j=1; j<nsegs; j++) {
        for (int i = 0;i<seglen;i++){

            if (smax < spec[i][j]) {
                smax =  spec[i][j];  // new maximum
            }else if(smin > spec[i][j]) {
                smin=spec[i][j];   // new maximum
            }
        }
    }
    return smax;
}
/**
 * Calculates the min and max value of the framed signal
 * @param spec
 * @param seglen
 * @param nsegs
 * @return
 */
public static float minmax(float[][] spec, int seglen, int nsegs) {

    min = (float) 1e35;
    max = (float) -1e35;
    for (int j=1; j<nsegs; j++) {
        for (int i = 0;i<seglen;i++){

            if (max < spec[i][j]) {
                max =  spec[i][j];  // new maximum
            }else if(min > spec[i][j]) {
                min=spec[i][j];   // new maximum
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

/**
 * Calculates the mean of the framed signal
 * @param nsegs
 */
private void meansig(int nsegs) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int j=1; j<(int)nsegs; j++) {
        for (int i = 0;i<seg_len;i++){

            sum += framed[i][j];
        }
    }


    sum = sum/(nsegs*seg_len);
    smux = sum;


}

/**
 * Frames up input audio
 * @return
 */

public float[][] FrameSig(){
    float [][] temp = new float [seg_len][(int)n_segs];
    float [][] frame = new float [seg_len][(int)n_segs];
    float padlen = (n_segs-1)*n_shift+seg_len;
    Log.d("DEBUG10","padlen = "+padlen);
    Log.d("DEBUG10","len = "+array2.length);

    wn = hamming(seg_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_segs;i++){

        for (int j = 0;j<seg_len;j++){

            temp[j][i] = time_array[i*n_shift+j];//*wn[i];

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n_segs;i++){            // Windowing

        for (int j = 0;j<seg_len;j++){

            frame[j][i] = temp[j][i]*wn[j];

        }
    }
    return frame;

}
/**
 * Calculates a hamming window to reduce
 * spectral leakage
 * @param len
 * @return
 */
public float[] hamming(int len){
    float [] win = new float [len];
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        win[i] = (float) (0.54-0.46*Math.cos((2*Math.PI*i)/(len-1)));
    }
    return win;
}

private class calcSpec extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    int fs = 0; // Sampling frequency
    int nshift = 0;// Initialise frame shift
    int nlen = 0;// Initialise frame length
    float nsegs = 0 ; //Initialise the total number of frames
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        fs = WaveTools.getFs();
        nshift = (int) Math.floor(tshift*fs/1000); // frame shift in samples
        nlen = (int) Math.floor(tlen*fs/1000);  // frame length in samples
        Log.d("Spectrogram", "Nilai dari nlen " + nlen + " nilai dari nshift " + nshift);
        nsegs = 1+(float) (Math.ceil((audioBuf.length-(nlen))/(nshift)));
        specGram(audioBuf,nsegs,nshift,nlen);

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        left.setText("");
        left.setTextSize(4);
        for (int j = 0; j < nsegs ; j++){
            for (int i = 0; i < nlen; i++) {
                left.append(Integer.toString((int) spec[i][j])+" ");
            }
        }

    }

}}
```

my question is: what's wrong on my code? is there a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You could probably look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12387637/4513913

Comment: cannot resolve `getAssets()` method in `AssetManager` Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create asset folder by go to your source folder then right click

```
New->Folder->Asset Folder
```

then paste to file in that asset folder [look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sv2U.png)

note that asset folder comes under main folder