# List assets in a subdirectory using AssetManager.list()

Tags: java, android, android-assets, android-assetmanager

My application has an assets directory in which I've dumped a bunch of text files I need to load at runtime.

I have a directory full of assets of a particular type (i.e., "assets/subdir") and I want to load all of the files in this directory, one at a time.

I have code like this:

```java
AssetManager assetMgr = getAssets();
String[] assetsIWant = assetMgr.list("subdir");
for(String asset: assetsIWant) {
  doAssetyThing(asset);
}
```

I've tried a zillion different versions of the parameter to `assetMgr.list()` and am not getting anywhere.

If I use "/", I get back a list containing the "assets" directory, and a few random other items (META_INF, for example).  If I pass any other string (like "assets" or "assets/" or "/assets" or "/assets/" or "mysubdir" or "/mysubdir" or "assets/mysubdir" or ...) then I get back an empty array.

The documentation is unfortunately fairly incoherent.

Does anybody know what the correct formula for that list() parameter is?

Answer (score 37):

Passing an empty string seems to work for me.  I get a list of the files in my assets directory when I do the following:

```
AssetManager aMan = appContext.getAssets();
String[] filelist = aMan.list("");
```

Answer (score 29):

I ve use the following code to list the file name in assets/myFolder/:

```
String[] fileNames =getAssets().list("myFolder");
for(String name:fileNames){
     System.out.println(name);    
}
```

note that the parameter in the method list does not contains "/".

Answer (score 18):

When you need to have access to a folder down deeper in your hierarchy use

```
String[] fileNames =getAssets().list("myFolder"+File.separator+"mysubfolder");
```

instead of "/" inside the String, which would give you an empty String array as result.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why it works this way, but when I list `"/"`, I get root level stuff, not things from my `"assets"` directory.  I actually found no way to properly list my assets folder in the short time I spent trying.

The workaround I'm using is to create a `"subdir"` directory inside of my `"assets"` directory.  I put all the assets that I want to access in this `"subdir"`, and do:

`String[] assetsIWant = assetMgr.list("subdir");`

I don't know why `"/"` lists the `"assets"` directory itself as one of it's files, yet you don't have to specify the `"assets"` directory when giving `list` a path.  Maybe someone else knows, but I hope this tip will help you out anyway.

Comment: "/" point to the root folder of your app. "." points to the current (assets) folder.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of similar questions around this topic, I suspect you are using the assets folder in a library project. if you try to access assets in a library project on android you will get empty contents and the exact symptoms you have described here

from the android "projects" documentation

source : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

> **Library projects cannot include raw assets**
>
> The tools do not support the use of raw asset files (saved in the assets/ directory) in
> a library project. Any asset resources used by an application must be
> stored in the assets/ directory of the application project itself.
> However, resource files saved in the res/ directory are supported.

if this is the case, the answer is that you should only include Raw assets in the assets folder of your application project *NOT* in any project marked as a library (you can check this by right clicking your project and selecting properties, select the android entry on the left and look at the is library checkbox)

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have this folder set up: `Assets->SubDir1`. You have things in `Subdir1` like `A.txt`, `B.txt`, `C.txt`. So from the Project's directory, it would be `Assets/SubDir1/A.txt`.

Taking that into account, the way to access that file is similar to what you're doing, adding one thing. That one thing is in your `doAssetyThing` function. You have to put the `SubDir1` directory in front of it, even if you did a filter of `"SubDir1"` in the `.list("");`

Example:

```
    AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
    String [] list = am.list("SubDir1");
    for (String s:list) {
        doAssetyThing("SubDir1/" + s);

        //I use this next line as the start of copying a pdf from one location
        //to another. I wanted to give you a real function in use.

        InputStream inStream = am.open("SubDir1/" + s);

        //more code
    }
```

I hope this is clear and helps you out!

Answer (score 2):

I use the following two methods to ensure given asset is present:

```
    protected boolean hasAsset(String id) {
    return hasAsset(id,"");
}

protected boolean hasAsset(String id, String dir) {
    int idx = id.indexOf('/');
    if (idx > 0 && idx < id.length() - 1) {
        if (dir.length() > 0) {
            dir = dir + "/" + id.substring(0,idx);
        } else
            dir = id.substring(0,idx);
        return hasAsset(id.substring(idx + 1), dir);
    }
    try {
        return Arrays.asList(context.getAssets().list(dir)).contains(id);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, empty directories are not listed.

At least, in my experience, they are not listed.

That is, if you have some-dir/d1/f1 and some-dir/d2 in the assets area, and you list("some-dir"), d2 is not listed.

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems working for me:
Keep a copy of each file you want to access from a sub directory in the assets directory too.
Use same convention. i.e. `list("subdirectory")`

It doesn't read the files in assets folder, but reads all "copied" files in its sub directory.
Weird!! But works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Kotlin:

```kotlin
val assetManager = context.resources.assets
assetManager
    .list("myDirectoryNameInAssetsFolder")
    .also { Log.i("Meow", "Detected files: ${it?.joinToString()}") }
    ?.map { "myDirectoryNameInAssetsFolder/$it" }
    ?.map(assetManager::open)
    ?.map { it.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText) }
    ?.also { Log.i("Meow", "Text of each file:") }
    ?.forEach { fileText -> Log.i("Meow", fileText) }
    ?: error("Could not access/read files in assets folder")
```