# android assetManager

Tags: android, assets

I need to get Absolute path to Folder in Assets.
Some like this for sd-card:

```
final String sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Files";
```

What i do incorrect?

[image]

First I try to get path (in green ractangle) this way but I alwase get "False".
Then I comment this block and try to get path from getAssets().list();
But I get 3 folders witch I see first time.

I want to make massive like this "green" but I need to use files from assets:

[Look the image](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/10682/20111213-qoze-610kb.jpg)

Help me to get absolute path to my Files folder.

Comment: [Look the screen](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/10682/20111213-pxu2-587kb.jpg)

How to create the same massive like "green", but using files from assets not sd-card?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, so I'll try to cover the bases, and maybe this will help.

- If you are just trying to get a list of what's in your assets, then
  use `getAssets().list("Files")`.  (You have to use the subdirectory,
  because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295538/324625)).
- If you are trying to get an *absolute* path to your assets directory
  (or any subdirectory), you can't. Whatever is in the assets directory
  is in the APK. It's not in external storage like on an SD card.
- If you are trying to open up files in the assets directory, use
  `AssetManager.open(filename)` to get the `InputStream`. Here, 
  filename should be the relative path from the assets directory.

---

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what you mean by "massive", but if you want to load the file `black.png` from assets instead of the SD card, then write this:

```
// must be called from Activity method, such as onCreate()
AssetManager assetMgr = this.getAssets();
mColors = new Bitmap[] {
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetMgr.open("black.png"));
    // and the rest
};
```

Comment: [Look the screen](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/10682/20111213-pxu2-587kb.jpg)

How to create the same massive like "green", but using files from assets not sd-card?

Answer (score 1):

Assets are stored in the APK file so there are no absolute path than your application can use. But, I would suggest to take a look at file:///android_asset. It might fits your needs. [Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320288/displaying-android-asset-files-in-a-webview) on how to display an Asset in a WebView.

Comment: I need this path to my Files folder to use images and sounds from this folder. How can I do this using this example? In it used WebView and URL, not the absolute path.