# Show a list of all XML filenames in the res folder for an Android application

Tags: android, xml, list, resources, filenames

I'm simply trying to get a list of all the XML files in my res/xml folder. I have tried to use the asset manager .list() function, but that doesn't seem to return anything. I have tried other methods, but none seem to work. They either fail, or return nothing.

This is simply so I can show a ListView which contains the name of each file.

Does anyone have any ideas of what is necessary to do this?

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495585/how-can-i-get-a-directory-listing-of-resources-from-my-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move them to `assets/xml`, then you can list them with `assetManager.list("xml")`