# How can I copy something from my app's storage into /system/?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to store a file on my app's storage (for example inside `/raw/` or `/assets/`) and copy it into a folder inside a folder in `/system/`, I know it needs root access and to make the system partition writable, and I did it with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o rw,remount /system/");
```

But I can't just use `cp` or `cat` for some unknown reasons, what's the best and easiest way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19218775/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/q/22903540/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare Can't make that to work for me, I don't know why tho

Comment: You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, providing a [mcve] showing what you tried. In there, explain in detail what "Can't make that to work for me" means.