# Include external content to Android project

Tags: android, apk, project, external

It's possible to add external content (for example a Zip that contains maps) to an Android Project and at the first start of the application move it to storage/emulated/0  or /sdcard/ or another generic path? How?

Comment: You can add it to the assets folder and on app start you can copy the content to a directory on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your zip file in the `assets` folder, then make a validation of if the file exists already in your generic path, if there is not then start with the copy.

To create your assets folder in Android Studio:

**Right click your app folder from the Android view** > **New** > **New Folder** > **Assets folder** > **Press finish**.

Paste your zip file there, and it will be contained in your next generated apk file.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387637/how-to-access-file-under-assets-folder-in-android), Nermeen provides a good way to access the files in your assets folder, here is the code:

> This will list all the files in the assets folder:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); 
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

> This to open a certian file:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open(assetName);
```

Then you can check if the file has already been copied, or not. You can check any of the following answers to do it.

[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)

[Copy directory from Assets to local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574983/copy-directory-from-assets-to-local-directory)