# Fast copy subfolder from assets in Android?

Tags: android, file-handling, android-assets

I have seen many example in SO how to move files from `assets`. All of them copy files one by one, not as part of a sub folder, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574983/copy-directory-from-assets-to-local-directory).

Is it possible to move a sub folder to a target location? If I have more thousand small files then it seems faster, than treating each file independently.

Comment: You can put files in subfolders of course. But every file has to be copied on it's own. But what does it matter? You use a loop and recursion. Files on a 'normal' place have to be copied one by one too.

Comment: `how to move files from assets`. You cannot `move` from assets. Only `copy` as assets is read only.

Comment: It is not to difficult to make a recursive functions that copies all files and folders and subfolders to a place on the file system. You do not have to know the names of files and folders for that at forehand.

Comment: Not diffucult, but takes time for system to accomplish, and until this I need to freez gui.

Comment: Well then put it in a thread or asynctask.

Comment: it will not faster on async task

Comment: Nobody who suggested that. And you were complaining about gui i thought. This was the solution for your complaint `and until this I need to freez gui.`. So do not  give my words a different twist please.