# Get duration of audio file on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, cocos2d-x-3.0

I fail at getting the duration of an in-bundle audio file on Android.

I tried this:

```
        String stringDuration;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            mmr.setDataSource(fullpath);
            stringDuration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            debugalert("androidbridgeGetdurationofsound IllegalArgumentException error getting duration: " + e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            debugalert("androidbridgeGetdurationofsound Exception error getting duration: " + e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
        finally {
            mmr.release();
        }
```

It always fails with the IllegalArgumentException exception. I'm not sure if the path is incorrect (tried a few variants), the media is not supported (tried m4a and wav) by that MediaMetadataRetriever class or what. The audio itself plays fine on Android.

A few path variants I tried are:

- assets/Assets/sounds/_TESTSOUNDWAVE.wav
- android.resource://com.package.name/assets/Assets/sounds/_TESTSOUNDWAVE.wav

I am using Cocos2D-x v3.6. There is no inherent (working, afaik) way of getting the duration of audio files in there (tried using AudioEngine).
The above code is from a static method on an activity called through JNI from the C++ side of Cocos2D-x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out Cocos2D-x somehow gave me incorrect exact paths to asset files! I was using the singleton File-something-class to get the exact paths on the C++ side and sent those paths to the platform side (iOS or Android). Always worked on iOS. For some reason it didn't work with Android.

A working path on the Android side was: **Assets/sounds/_TESTSOUNDWAVE.wav**

I had to specifically remove the "assets/" from the beginning of the string (`fullpath = fullpath.replaceAll("^assets/", "");`). Might be something funny with my setup, or there's a problem in Cocos2d-x. Who knows.

How I figured the exact paths out was to recursively list all stuff in the bundle: [How can I get a directory listing of resources from my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495585/how-can-i-get-a-directory-listing-of-resources-from-my-android-app)